# Dynamics 365 Web API: Saved Query does not retrieve related entity's all columns

Tags: client-side-scripting, dynamics-365

In Web API(client side), trying to retrieve records of OpportunityProduct entity using  SavedQuery(view).

Able to retrieve existing product's name(Product entity's lookup values), however, same result does not contain all attributes of Product entity, although they are added onto the View I'm retrieving and **value of those attribute are not empty**.

Here's the code, used to retrieve SavedQuery:

```
        var products = [];
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/opportunityproducts?savedQuery=********-****-****-****-************", true);
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
                req.onreadystatechange = null;
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                    console.log(results);
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                        var product = {
                            "Number": results.value[i]["productnumber"],
                            "Name": results.value[i]["_productid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                            "Unit": results.value[i]["_uomid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                            "PricePerUnit": results.value[i]["priceperunit@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                            "Quantity": results.value[i]["quantity@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                            "Discount": results.value[i]["manualdiscountamount@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
                            "Discount%": results.value[i]["pub_discountpercentage"],
                            "ExtendedAmount": results.value[i]["extendedamount@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"]
                        };
                        console.log(product);
                        products.push(product);
                    }
                } else {
                    window.parent.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
                }
            }
        };
        req.send();
```

Here's the result:

```
"value": [
    {
        "producttypecode": 1,
        "priceperunit": 100,
        "extendedamount": 190,
        "sequencenumber": 1,
        "quantity": 2,
        "opportunityproductid": "********-****-****-****-************",
        "manualdiscountamount": 10,
        "productdescription": "Test 1",
        "isproductoverridden": true
    }
]
```

[image: Shows columns available in View]

In attached image, please see the highlighted `Discount %` column which is custom attribute on Product entity that I'm trying to retrieve.

Can anyone guide me how can I retrieve related entity's(Product) attributes or all columns specified on View?

Comment: Is that a calculated field? Datatype?

Comment: @ArunVinoth, No its not a calculated field. It's datatype is "Decimal Number".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting some efforts this morning, I learned that when `Product` is added as `Existing Product` in `OpporutnityProduct`, then you can retrieve all fields of View on `opportunityProduct`, regardless of whether they belongs to `OpporutnityProduct` entity or any of its related entity.

But when `Product` is added as `Write-in Product`, then you can retrieve fields that belongs to `OpportunityProduct` entity only.

I was not able to find `Discount %` column of `Product` entity because `Product` was added using `Write-in Product` option.

When I added a `Product` using `Existing Product` option, I could retrieve it using the same piece of code.

Hope this will be helpful.